# Is it possible to include reusable html/asp files?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In .Net mvc 4 is it possible to include re-usable html files within View pages?  The scenario I have is to easily include dialogs in different web pages - say dlgLogon.js - easy to include as a javascript include, but alo requires its related dialog html/asp.

I don't want the files in a Master page as not pages will require them.

I'm coming from the java world where nesting jspf'(jsp fragments ) s is common.

Comment: Your tagging is very confusing. Why the asp-classic tag? Your text does not give any indication that you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

> In .Net mvc 4 is it possible to include re-usable html files within View pages?

You could use [partial views](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'd used Partial a month or 2 ago to create some nice panels, completely forgot about them.  I'll revist tonight. Thanks.